# str_replace double and single quotes

Tags: php, escaping, str-replace

I have a simple PHP script that should escape both single and double quotes with a backslash. Here is my code:

```
$output = str_replace('"','\"',$input);
$output = str_replace("'","\'",$output);
return $output;
```

Problem is, it only escapes the double quote, so a string like

```
"This" is a 'string'
```

parses out to be

```
\"This\" is a 'string'
```

not

```
\"This\" is a \'string\'
```

If I change the second line to

```
$output = str_replace("'","asdf",$output);
```

I get

```
\"This\" is a asdfstringasdf
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @symlynk I have had no problem with your code, how did you declare your `$input` ?

Comment: It's a string variable stored in a CMS.

Comment: I know it has been solved, but you could use [addslashes](http://www.php.net/addslashes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I was viewing the output in my browser's console, which for some reason was showing the backslash for double quotes, but not singles. View source showed that it was working properly.

Comment: Great! Keep in mind also that ' and " are escape characters and should be treated as such in the future. That will cause you the least trouble.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have a problem with your code, my test is below:

```
<?php

    $input = '"This" is a '."'".'String'."'";
    echo $input.'<br />';
    //Echos  "This" is a 'String'

    $output = str_replace('"','\"',$input);
    $output = str_replace("'","\'",$output);
    echo $output;
    //Echos  \"This\" is a \'String\'
```

**Edited**

Irrelevant now, OP figured it out :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$output = str_replace("\"","\\\"",$input);
$output = str_replace("\'","\\\'",$output);
return $output;
```

The problem is that ' inside a string, should be noted as \' , as it is an escape character. The backslash \ is a double \ as well inside a string.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: This still produces the same result. double quotes are escaped, single quotes are ignored.

Comment: Can you show me your input string? And do you have other str_replaces?